# How can/should I include annotated images?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

It's often the case that I'd like to include some graphic in a LaTeX document and overlay it with some text or other annotation, maybe including arrows or other simple graphics. The annotations can be easily handled using TikZ, so obviously if I create the graphic itself in TikZ, I'm all set. But sometimes the graphic is very complex and it's not practical to recreate it with TikZ commands. In these cases, I would like to include the graphic file directly, but still be able to layer my annotations over it. Editing the image to include the annotation is a possibility, but I'd really like to avoid that because the annotations then wouldn't reflect the document's font style and size, and also because it'd be harder to change them.

Is there a preferred way to include an external image and then layer additional content over it? A solution that lets me continue to use TikZ for the annotations is preferred, but not required.

**EDIT:** All three answers (`overpic`, a TikZ node, and `\pgftext`) work fine, but unfortunately I can only accept one, so I'm going with the one recommended in the "official source," the TikZ manual.

Comment: Related: [Drawing on an image with TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171483/mathematical-formulas-on-a-graph-not-made-by-tex/171486#171486

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The pgf/TikZ manual suggests using the command `\pgftext` to insert external graphics (section 53.3.3 "Inserting Text and Images").  Here's an example taken from [this seminar](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Seminars/chern.html) (slides 5 and 6 in the presentation version):

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftext{%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Bridge05a}%
}%
\node[fill=black, opacity=.5, text opacity=1] at (0,.5) {\Large \color{yellow} Geometry};
\node[fill=black, opacity=.5, text opacity=1] at (0,-.5) {\Large \color{red} \emph{Manifolds}};
\node[fill=black, opacity=.5, text opacity=1] at (-4,.5) {\Large \color{yellow} Algebra};
\node[fill=black, opacity=.5, text opacity=1] at (4,.5) {\Large \color{yellow} Analysis};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

There is also a *hint* elsewhere in the manual (in 53.3.1) that the command `\pgfimage` can be used instead of `\includegraphics` (although still within the `\pgftext` command); however, searching for `\pgfimage` in the manual doesn't turn up any further explanation of this command.

---

The `\pgftext` command is something of a special command.  It "escapes" out of the current picture back to "normal TeX".  It is, therefore, somewhat like a `\node` command.  It works by constructing a box which is then put into the picture.  By default this box is put at the current origin.  A simple way to move it, therefore, is to (temporarily) tell TikZ/PGF to move the origin priori to issuing the `\pgftext` command.

An alternative way of positioning it is to use the initial optional argument.  Thus one can say `\pgftext[<positioning information>]{text}` where `<positioning information>` is some set of PGF keys that relocate the box.  These are similar to the positioning of a `\node`, but have a slightly "low level" feel to them.  For example, to locate the box at a particular point one would say `\pgftext[at={\pgfpoint{1cm}{2cm}}]{text}`.  Note the `\pgfpoint` syntax rather than the TikZ coordinate syntax.

In the 2.10-CVS version of the manual, the `\pgftext` command is documented in Section 77.3.3.  There is also some important information about how it interacts with scopes in Section 77.1.2 (note especially item 5 about the ability to put another `pgfpicture` inside a `\pgftext` command, something that should never be done with `\node`!).

In summary, `\pgftext` is somewhat akin to `\node` in that it allows you to put "normal TeX" in your picture.  However, the two are different in that a `\node` is considered part of the picture but `\pgftext` is for things that are meant to be somewhat separate.

Comment: In the newest CVS versions of the manual, the following statements is present: "To be quite frank, LATEX’s \includegraphics is designed better than pgf’s image mechanism" in section 81.1.  The manual goes on to explain that `\pgfimage` is primarily intended for use with plain TeX which has no "out of the box" support for image inclusion.

Comment: For the record, I did some hunting and found that `\pgfuseimage` is part of a pair: first `\pgfdeclareimage[options]{name}{filename}` to declare the image, then `\pgfuseimage{name}` to actually include it. Pretty much the same way shadings work. Good to know it's maybe not the optimal method, though.

Comment: One advantage of `\pgfdeclareimage`...`\pgfuseimage` over `\includegraphics` is with beamer: if you have an image on a frame with multiple overlays, the latter will embed the image into the pdf once for each overlay.  The former will embed it once and reuse it in later overlays.

Comment: @PaulGaborit Using `\node` is Sharpie's answer so the content of your suggestion is already present in this list of answers.  If, as you say (and I'm prepared to believe you), it is the Right Way To Do Things then perhaps you could add a comment to Sharpie's answer explaining why, then others can make an informed choice.  It's pretty clear from the edit to the question that all answers work so if you provide some concrete reason to prefer one over another then that will help others decide which one to use.

Comment: @PaulGaborit I've looked at that question and that is due to a misunderstanding of how to use `\pgftext` in that it is embedded in a `\node` which it shouldn't be.

Comment: @PaulGaborit How's that?

Comment: @PaulGaborit What do you think to a clean-up of these comments, then?

Answer (score 7):

Using TikZ, you can include the image inside a `\node`:

```
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
  (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics{image}};
```

Then draw away:

```
\draw (image.south west) -- ++(1,1);

\coordinate[at = 1in of image.west] (pathStart);
\draw (pathStart) -- ++(42,13);

% Etc.
```

There is a complete example [at this site](http://kogs-www.informatik.uni-hamburg.de/~meine/tikz/).

If you are creating graphics such as plots, you can use the [R](http://www.r-project.org) programming language along with the [tikzDevice](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tikzDevice/index.html) package that an associate and I developed.  The tikzDevice encodes graphics created by R into TeX commands.  We just released a new version, 0.5.0, that includes support for inserting named coordinates into the generated figures so that they may be further annotated by TikZ commands.

Comment: Just to note: TikZ can also use gnuplot to generate plots: gnuplot figures out the data points and TikZ renders them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't really have a use for R/tikzDevice. The particular image that prompted me to ask this question was a 5MB PDF so I expect it would be an unreasonably long list of TikZ commands.

Answer (score 6):

The [`overpic` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/overpic.html) sounds to be just what you're after.  From the package description:

> The overpic environment is a cross between the LaTeX picture environment and the \includegraphics command of graphicx. The resulting picture environment has the same dimensions as the included eps graphic. LaTeX commands can be placed on the graphic at defined positions. A grid for orientation is available.

Note that it is possible to use other graphics formats besides .eps -- anything you'd be able to use with `\includegraphics` will still work with this package.

Answer (score 4):

As already suggested, you can annotate the different parts of the figure [using TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9561/76206). However, sometimes it might even better to use numbers to reference the different parts and explain them in the figure caption.

To easily **get the precise relative positions** (which is often quite tedious) and to generate LaTeX code automatically for such example as shown below, you could use the new web-based [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/), which I built for such cases. This is just a small interactive tool, which helps you to find the right locations without using a manual [grid-based approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/9562/76206).

[image: Example]

## LaTeX Code

In the following the source code of a minimal working example generated by the [**LaTeX Overlay Generator**](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/).

```
\documentclass{article}

% remove "[demo]" if you want include actual image!!!
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX Overlay Generator - Annotated Figures v0.0.1
% Created with http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}{box-color}{label-color}{border-color}{text-color}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at (#4) [fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}
%\annotatedFigureBox{bottom-left}{top-right}{label}{label-position}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{white}{black}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}[h!t]

        \begin{annotatedFigure}
            {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{black-demo.png}}
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.084,0.614}{0.394,0.804}{A}{0.084,0.614}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.222,0.284}{0.3743,0.4934}{B}{0.3743,0.4934}%tr
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.555,0.784}{0.6815,0.874}{C}{0.555,0.784}%bl
            \annotatedFigureBox{0.557,0.322}{0.8985,0.5269}{D}{0.8985,0.5269}%tr
        \end{annotatedFigure}

        \caption{\textbf{Lorum Ipsum Overview} -- Lorem ipsum dolor amet (A), consetetur (B) elitr, sed diam (C) nonumy eirmod invidunt ut labore (D).}
        \label{fig:teaser}

    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I assume, the Generator provides the code as well. Could you post such code in order to make the answer reproducible?

Comment: I've modified my post to include the source code which was created using the overlay generator tool.

Comment: Looks awesome. However, If try "Choose File" I can select a file, but it seems to get never uploaded. Also the LaTeX code doesn't change. (Safari 7.1.4  on MacOS  10.9.5)

Comment: I can't test it with Safari right now, but Chrome should work. You could also try to select an image file (jpg or png) instead of a pdf file, to see if this makes a different in Safari. I will look into possible Safari issues soon.