# What is the advantage of using \includegraphics instead of \pgfimage for ordinary image inclusion?

Tags: graphics, pgf-core

The TikZ & PGF manual says that ‘LaTeX’s `\includegraphics` is designed better than pgf’s image mechanism’ and that ‘LaTeX users are encouraged to use `\includegraphics` to include images.’ But is there any advantage of using `\includegraphics` instead of `\pgfimage` when **not** using any of the features exclusive to `\includegraphics` (such as clipping)?

The only differences I’ve found is that `latexmk` automatically recognises modified images when `\includegraphics` is used, but not when `\pgfimage` is used. On the other hand, `\pgfimage` supports the `interpolate` option, which is nice (though not widely supported in PDF readers). `\pgfimage` also supports masking, which `\includegraphics` does not. One last difference I’ve found is that `\pgfimage` only issues a warning, not an error, when a referenced image is not found. This may of course be both positive and negative; personally, I like it.

Are there any other important differences and advantages of using `\includegraphics` over `\pgfimage`?

Comment: Have a look at answers and comments here: [How can/should I include annotated images?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/how-can-should-i-include-annotated-images).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\pgfimage` currently uses `\includegraphics` internally for every output format (i.e. driver) except for `pdftex` where it uses its own `pdftex` primitives to include the image (which are also used in `\includegraphics` BTW). 
A notable difference is that PGF provides different macros to declare the image first and then use it multiple times, while `\includegraphics` doesn't, nevertheless `\includegraphics` will also only store the image once in the PDF.

Note that since 2010/09/09 the `pdftex` driver for `graphicx` has supported the `interpolate` option. This isn't mentioned in the `graphicx` manual which seems to be frozen. I found it in the source file comments:

```
% 2010/09/09 v0.05a (HO)
% [..]
%  * Option `interpolate' added for bitmaps, see PDF specification.
%    Values are `true' or `false', default is `false'.
```

So you can use it as:

```
\includegraphics[interpolate=true]{<image>}
% or simply
\includegraphics[interpolate]{<image>}
```

Also a very big difference (IMHO) is that `\includegraphics` can use most of the new keys provided by my `adjustbox` package as long it is loaded with the `export` option. It provides frames, min/max sizes, multiple clippings, size adjustments, and more.

In summary, I think what is meant by the notice that "`\includegraphics` is designed better", is that it comes already with all needed drivers which are stable and tested through decades of usage. Apparently PGF doesn't have all its image related code finished for its driver files, otherwise it wouldn't fall-back to `\includegraphics` for most drivers.

Comment: Although it mentions "...see PDF specification", I have no idea where to start looking for that. Do you know what `interpolate` does to/for BMPs?

Comment: @Werner: It interpolates the image (raster images only) when zoomed. You then don't see the pixels any longer if you use very high zoom factors.

Comment: You said that `\includegraphics` includes a multiple used image only once too. So if I like to include e.g. a (vector) logo in all footers it doesn’t matter wether I use `\includegraphics` or the PGF mechanism?

Comment: @Tobi: Yes, using `\includegraphics` in a header or footer with a vector or raster image will only include the image once, if you use `pdftex`. With PGF you should use `\pgfdeclareimage` once in the preamble and use `\pgfuseimage` in the header or footer.