# Losing the quality of the image in lyx

Tags: graphics, lyx, png, resolution

I have been looking for a possible answer for this problem (it seems that I am not the only one facing this), but the answers do not help too much.

I got this image (.png) which I consider having a good quality even when I see it in lyx. But as soon as I create the pdf (using pdflatex) the resolution of the image decrease as you can see.
[image]
[image]

I got not idea about why this is happening, almost everyone in other answers says that .png images should appear like they are.

Do you have any idea about this?

Maybe there are crutches that can solve this problem?

Comment: PNG is a raster graphics type. When it is scaled (especially to be made larger), the image will lose visual quality. (This is one of the reasons it is preferable to use vector graphics, such as PDF, instead of the far more common raster graphics.)

Comment: @user2343521: I think this is the same problem as [My pixel perfect picture gets blurry when compiled in LaTex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10975/my-pixel-perfect-picture-gets-blurry-when-compiled-in-latex/10978#10978): The image is unchanged, but the viewer (like Acrobat Reader) smoothes it.

Comment: Sean Allred, thanks a lot for your replay. Before to put this question I looked for some reasons and in almost all of them the answer said that pdflatex do not change the quality of the images. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38555/image-quality-using-pdflatex

Comment: @user2343521: Have you tried opening the file in a different viewer or disabling the image smoothing in the viewer?

Comment: @Jake Nothing seems to work, I have used different viewer but result are even worst in some cases.

Comment: Have you changed the scale or size of the image in LyX?

Comment: Yes I have, I used a "reduction factor"(?) for every images I'm using, the thing is these images are not so big to present this decrease on their quality when I re sized the graphics. Or at least that is what I have understood.

Comment: Honestly, I've never tested properly to see what happens to the quality of images when resized, but try turning off the resizing and see what the result is. If there is no difference, then at least you've ruled out one possible cause.

Comment: Have you tried to convert the PNG to something else (say, JPG)? Maybe  that would help.

Comment: Resizing a raster image in anyway at all is not likely to turn out well.