# Insert pgf with referenced png file from a different folder

Tags: pgfplots, input, import, folders

I'm trying to insert a `pgf` file that I made with matplotlib. This file references to a `png` file (since I inserted a png figure in the plot).

When I put the png in the same folder than my `tex` file, everything works, but if the png file is in the folder with the pgf file, i got an error

```
Package pgf Warning: File "plot2.png" not found when def
ining image "pgflastimage".
```

I was trying to use `import` but I don't know how it works for a pgf. If I change pgf by tex, it still doesn't find the png:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}


% \subimport{../pgf/}{plot.pgf} --> Not working
\input{../pgf/plot.pgf}

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Changing `\pgfimage{...}` by `\includegraphics{...}` in the pgf file, seems to work with `subimport*` . However, matplotlib produces the pgf with `pgfimage`, so it would be necessary to change the output plots by hand. Maybe someone knows a better solution.

Comment: Where? In the pgf file? =o

Comment: Same problem here. I didn't find a proper answer yet..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: The `matplotlib` backend [has been updated](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10963) to emit `\includegraphics` instead of `\pgfimage`.  The best solution is to update `matplotlib` if possible.

---

#### Original Answer

From what I found, there is no better way.  [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32989/61112) notes that `pgfimage` uses `includegraphics`, but does not propagate the relative paths.  Looking through the [matplotlib pgf backend source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py#L658), changing `pgfimage` to `includegraphics` does not appear to be a configurable option on the `matplotlib` side of the equation.

A work around I came up with was to intercept the output and update the appropriate lines.

```
# lots of plotting commands
fig.savefig(output)
_, ext = os.path.splitext(output)
if ext == ".pgf":
    with open(output, "r") as fid:
        lines = fid.readlines()

    with open(output, "w") as fid:
        for line in lines:
            fid.write(re.sub(r"\\pgfimage", r"\\includegraphics", line))
```

This is really only a “solution” if you can edit the plotting routines.

Comment: [Chatter is happening on the matplotlib issue list](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/10963) to update the backend to emit `\includegraphics` instead of `\pgfimage`. Hopefully they can resolve the testing issues soon that are holding up the fix.