# Switching from PDFLaTeX to XeLaTeX is messing with my pgftext coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex

I'm working on a template for an automated report (using `knitr`). I created a title banner for my organization using TikZ; the last step to finish the branding was to switch to my organization's fonts. For this, I switched to XeLaTeX--my first time using it. The fonts work great! But the position of the logo in my `tikzpicture` got messed up, and I can't seem to do anything with it.

Minimal Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (1in, 1in) {\pgftext{\includegraphics[height=0.3in]{mylogo}}};
    \node at (5in, 5in) {\pgftext{\includegraphics[height=0.3in]{mylogo}}};
    \node at (2in, 2in) {First one};
    \node at (3in, 3in) {Second one};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

When I run `PDFLaTeX` on the above code, everything works as expected: I see two logos, and both text nodes. If I run `XeLaTeX`, the normal text nodes still work as expected, but I only see one logo in the top left (I think they're both printed there). The question is: How can I position the image while using `XeTeX`?

The `mylogo` file is a `.png`, not that I can imagine that affecting anything. I'm running MiKTeX on a Windows box; I just ran the updater so everything should be up to date.

Comment: Remove `\pgftext`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `\pgftext` is supposed to do, but it seems to be the problem. Removing it should put the logos where they should.

Comment: I got the `\pgftext` from [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1466/10371) and never tried without it, but it does seem completely extraneous.

Comment: @shujaa `\pgftext` escapes back to "ordinary TeX" from the PGF environment.  However, you're using inside a `\node` where you are *already* "escaped" back to TeX.  Therefore it is superfluous and only good fortune meant that it had no effect with `pdflatex`!