# Image overlay generator - How to annotate sub-images in the center of each overlay box? (caption-diagram next to original image)

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

The [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/) is a great tool to annotate sub-images of an image in a LaTeX-caption way. It names itself "Visual Overlay Generator v0.0.1", as it creates a visual overlay: a diagram which is overlayed on the original image.

The same LaTeX Overlay Generator was the base of [User f2cx's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/238504/67761) to the OP [How can/should I include annotated images?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1449/how-can-should-i-include-annotated-images/238504#238504).

However, I am looking for a different way to annotate sub-images of an image. That is:

- They don't have to be "captions" in a Tex-sense: they can be plain text.
- The visual overlay from the "Visual Overlay Generator" should be added on the right side of the original image (cf. the **left-right** layout in the example images below for better understanding ... alternatively they can be **top-bottom** sometimes, when one is dealing with "wide" images).
- The text of the captions should be added within the visual overlay, rather than below the original image.

Let's take the following image (containing sub-images) as an example (the different sub-images are represented by different colours, just as an example):

[image: Image with sub-images]

Then, the following is what I would like to end up with (the original image **on the left**, and an annotation-diagram **on the right**, where captions can be added via Tex in the center of each box in the annotation-diagram):

[image: Image on the left, and annotation-diagram with captions on the right]

Although, I personally think it doesn't aid the clarity of the caption-diagram, the following could be an optional variant of that, where the **right side** also features the original image as a background (with an opacity of ±20%):

[image: Variant with original image as background, with low opacity]

I have no clue of an elegant way to achieve this in Tex. Perhaps it could be (sped up) possible with the help of a GUI, such as a vector image creator (e.g. GIMP, Inkscape, Adobe Illustrator, ...)? The "overlay"-annotation-diagram could then be traced easily in such a software, and the diagram could then be exported as a SVG. Unfortunately, I do not know how one could then use Tex to annotate (write actual comments) the different "objects" (read: rectangles representing sub-images in the diagram), e.g. in the center of each "object" (read: rectangle).

Any advice (for sticking with Tex to achieve the result, or if not: avoiding it) or a workable solution please? I will need this process to create many (more than 100) images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the custom code generated from [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/v0.0.1) can be used and altered minimally in the following way:

- `\node at (#4)` should be replaced by `\node at ($ (#1)!.5!(#2) $)`, which will place the label in the middle of the rectangles (instead of taking an optional 4-th argument);
- to make the previous step work, one needs to include `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` below `\usepackage{tikz}`;
- `{white}{white}{black}{black}` can be changed to `{white}{none}{none}{black}` to delete the white circle with the black border;
- `[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image)` can be changed to `[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=0.2] (image)` to give a 20% opacity to the background image;
- Presuming you had an overlay-rectangle generated with the default "code" `{A}`, one can change this to `{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}`.

So, imagine we want to work with the following code, generated via [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/v0.0.1) (I just deleted the comment lines, as well as `\caption{...}` & `\label{fig:teaser}`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at (#4) [fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{white}{black}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!t]

\begin{annotatedFigure}
    {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{qUq7A.jpg}}
    \annotatedFigureBox{0.1113,0.5114}{0.625,0.7951}{A}{0.1113,0.5114}
\end{annotatedFigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Then, we adapt it (following the steps described above), to achieve (I made the image smaller by changing `[width=1.0\linewidth]` to `[width=0.5\linewidth]`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at ($ (#1)!.5!(#2) $)[fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{none}{none}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=0.2] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!t]

\begin{annotatedFigure}
    {\includegraphics[width=1.0\linewidth]{qUq7A.jpg}}
    \annotatedFigureBox{0.1113,0.5114}{0.625,0.7951}{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}{0.1113,0.5114}
\end{annotatedFigure}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

That yields something as such (if one doesn't want the background image, one can change `opacity=0.2` to `opacity=0`, and depending on what is found below, you'll might want to change the colour of the roundd rectangle from `{white}` to e.g. `{red}`):

[image: Screenshot 1]

After this is done, one can put everything in a mini-page, to have 2 side-by-side figures, using (taken from [User Matthew Leingang's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5770/67761) in OP [Two figures side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5769/two-figures-side-by-side)):

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
% here should come all the code for the original image (left side)
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
% here should come all the code for the "overlay-image" (right side)
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Doing so, on the workflow above, yields (I went back from `[width=0.5\linewidth]` to `[width=1\linewidth]` here):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBoxCustom[8]{\draw[#5,thick,rounded corners] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at ($ (#1)!.5!(#2) $)[fill=#6,thick,shape=circle,draw=#7,inner sep=2pt,font=\sffamily,text=#8] {\textbf{#3}};}

\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[4]{\annotatedFigureBoxCustom{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{white}{none}{none}{black}}
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureText[4]{\node[draw=none, anchor=south west, text=#2, inner sep=0, text width=#3\linewidth,font=\sffamily] at (#1){#4};}
\newenvironment {annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0,opacity=0.2] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!t]

\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{qUq7A.jpg}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{annotatedFigure}
    {\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{qUq7A.jpg}}
    \annotatedFigureBox{0.1113,0.5114}{0.625,0.7951}{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}{0.1113,0.5114}
\end{annotatedFigure}
\end{minipage}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, (due to the lengthy `{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}` which doesn't fit onto the right image) the right-hand-side image gets pushed somewhat down; as can be noticed in the output:

[image: Screenshot 2]

Perhaps this could be fixed by limiting the width of the `{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}`, so that it receives automatic line-breaks (and/or reduction of its font-size, e.g. when line-breaks are no longer possible within the rectangle at a certain larger font-size)?

One way to limit the maximum width of the captions, is to introduce e.g. `, text width=30mm` after e.g. `text=#8`, but that would limit the width of all the captions. To limit the width for each caption, one can e.g. put a certain caption within a `\begin{minipage}{0.75\textwidth}`...`\end{minipage}`.

If you would like to use rotations on the rectangle, you would need to shift the text and the rectangles as well. This could be done using `xshift` and `yshift`. One could adapt the code generated from [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/v0.0.1) as such, to suit your needs:

```
\newcommand*\annotatedFigureBox[6]{\draw[orange,thick,rounded corners,rotate=#4, xshift=(#5), yshift=(#6)] (#1) rectangle (#2);\node at ($ (#1)!.5!(#2) $)[text=white] {\small{#3}};}
\newenvironment{annotatedFigure}[1]{\centering\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,opacity=0.3] (image) at (0,0) { #1};\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]}{\end{scope}\end{tikzpicture}}
```

Then, one could copy only the rectangle's coordinates as the first 2 arguments of any caption-box (`\annotatedFigureBox`), into the first 2 arguments of:

```
\annotatedFigureBox{x1-copy-from-generator,y1-copy-from-generator}{x2-copy-from-generator,y2-copy-from-generator}{the caption you'd like to give to the sub-image}{0}{0}{0}%bl
```

The last 2 arguments are `xshift` and `yshift` respectively, and the one before that (the 4th argument) is the rotation of the rectangle.

Nevertheless, the need for the manual use of `xshift` and `yshift` is not so elegant, and furthermore it is hard to guess the size and position of the rectangle in the [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/v0.0.1), if you'll need to rotate it afterwards. Therefor, it might be better to use another generator, from which you could retrieve the coordinates of points, to draw a rectangle or polygon (connect the dots).