# How to overlay (annotate) sub-images (rectangles; but not straight, maybe chopped off) an image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, annotations

The [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/) is a great tool to annotate images which contain sub-images like this (where the sub-images are all rectangles and all "horizontal with the screen"):

[image: All straight]

However, some images contain sub-images in the following manner (where they are not all "horizontal with the screen" and rectangles may be chopped off):

[image: Not straight and chopped off]

The [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/) unfortunately is not able to rotate rectangles ([I have tried to do it afterwards, but not in an easy manner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/311563/67761)), and even if it could, one would still need to find a way to "chop off" the whole image afterwards.

Perhaps there is another handy way with Tex then? For inspiration, cf. [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz). Or perhaps there is a GUI to make it happen?

*P.S.: I have added a green border on top of the polygons (all chopped-off rectangles), since that's a functionality of the [LaTeX Overlay Generator](http://ff.cx/latex-overlay-generator/#/) which I would like to preserve/mimic.*

*P.S.: I would also like to have text (annotations) inside the sub-images, in a later stage.*

Comment: I don't really see the point. Surely it would be easier in this case to just use TikZ to create the aggregate image and annotate it etc. as you go? Or use Inkscape which can produce TikZ code, if you want. (Is that what you want?) I'm not very clear if this is even definitely about TeX or really something else. Or if it might or might not be something else. Or ...?

Comment: @cfr You wrote: "`use Inkscape which can produce TikZ code`". That sounds very interesting to me: using a GUI but still reverting to all the code within a Tex document! Would you have any relevant link to advise on that please? (I guess perhaps [Exporting from Inkscape to LaTeX - via TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151232/exporting-from-inkscape-to-latex-via-tikz) on the SE-site, but it seems as if the text is fixed from within a seperate file and the paths are drawn within the SVG as well; I'd rather have it generated from within the main Tex document; e.g. by TikZ coordinates)?

Comment: I've only done it once, I think. Maybe I'm imagining the once. So I'm not really a good person to ask - sorry.

Comment: If the [LaTeX Overlay Generator](LaTeX Overlay Generator) could just generate coordinates, instead of rectangles, then that could be useful; as one could draw the polygons from them `\draw (x,y) -- (x,y) -- (x,y) -- ...; ` The fact that you need to draw a rectangle in the generator, is limiting the applicability of the tool. You could of course look for coordinates by taking e.g. the left-top corner of each rectangle, but it's quite labor-intensive.

Comment: So... er, why use it? If you use TikZ, you can specify whatever coordinates you like. I still don't get the point: the tool doesn't do what you want. Either you content yourself with what it does or you get the tool changed or you use another tool. Why isn't the last the obvious option here?

Comment: @cfr Ok, that sounds good: it would be best to use an other tool. But what other tool might be best? Would you know of any more or less automated/GUI-way please?

Comment: [I already suggested one.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311713/how-to-overlay-annotate-sub-images-rectangles-but-not-straight-maybe-choppe?noredirect=1#comment758086_311713) Note that 'automated' and 'GUI' are more-or-less anathema. I don't really understand what you mean about wanting it generated in the `.tex` file. The exported code ends up in the `.tex` file. If you don't want that, I don't see how you can want a GUI.